# Overlaying two Pandas DataFrames when one is partial

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to *either* overlay two dataframes, overwriting one with values from the other *if* the value in *several* columns match. I don't care about the indexes of the dataframes, what is pertinent is that content in the columns match for the overwrite to occur. It'd also be acceptable to *remove* the rows from one dataframe when this match occurs and just concat the remaining rows.

Below are two mocked up dataframes with simplified column names for brevity. The first is the "background" dataframe, the one on which I wish to overlay content from the other,

```
   Name1 Name2  Id1  Id2 Attr1 Attr2
3      A     B    0    0  None  None
1      A     B    0    1  None  None
7      A     B    0    2  None  None
15     A     B    0    3  None  None
13     A     B    1    0  None  None
14     A     B    1    1  None  None
0      A     B    1    2  None  None
4      A     B    1    3  None  None
10     A     B    2    0  None  None
9      A     B    2    1  None  None
12     A     B    2    2  None  None
11     A     B    2    3  None  None
6      A     B    3    0  None  None
8      A     B    3    1  None  None
2      A     B    3    2  None  None
5      A     B    3    3  None  None
```

The second contains some data

```
  Name1 Name2  Id1  Id2     Attr1  Attr2
0     A     B    0    0   LEVEL_A   1.00
1     A     B    0    1   LEVEL_A   0.97
2     A     B    1    1   LEVEL_A   1.00
3     A     B    2    2   LEVEL_A   1.00
4     A     B    3    3   LEVEL_A   1.00
```

I included the indices to show that they do not match. The expected result would *contain* this data:

```
   Name1 Name2  Id1  Id2 Attr1 Attr2
3      A     B    0    0  Level_A  1.00 # Name1,Name2,Id1,Id2 matches
1      A     B    0    1  Level_A  0.97
7      A     B    0    2  None  None
15     A     B    0    3  None  None
13     A     B    1    0  None  None
14     A     B    1    1  Level_A  1.00
0      A     B    1    2  None  None
4      A     B    1    3  None  None
10     A     B    2    0  None  None
9      A     B    2    1  None  None
12     A     B    2    2  Level_A  1.00
11     A     B    2    3  None  None
6      A     B    3    0  None  None
8      A     B    3    1  None  None
2      A     B    3    2  None  None
5      A     B    3    3  Level_A  1.00
```

Note: it's fine if the rows are in a different order in the end result. That would be expected if one finds all rows in the first dataframe such that for any given row its values for the columns `Name1,Name2,Id1,Id2` are also present in the second dataframe.

Bonus: I'd be very interested to know if it is possible to do this if one didn't use a sentinel value such as `None` and if possible, how?

I keep getting it wrong because `combine_first`, `isin` et al. all look at indices. Am dangerously close to doing this using some `iterrow`-approach but that feels hacky and I don't want to unit-test my unit-tests. Pandemic brain is making me not think as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check_cols = 'Name1 Name2 Id1 Id2'.split()
val_cols = 'Attr1 Attr2'.split()
```

Create unique ids

```
background_df['full_id'] = background_df[check_cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join([str(_).strip() for _ in row]), axis=1)
data_df['full_id'] = data_df[check_cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join([str(_).strip() for _ in row]), axis=1)
```

Merge on the unique id.
You can change suffixes to help you drop the extra columns later

```
background_df.merge(data_df, how='left', on='full_id', suffixes=('_x', '_y'))
```

then you would drop whatever columns you don't want **OR** just start the merge with fewer columns.

```
background_df[check_cols+['full_id',]].merge(data_df[val_cols+['full_id',]], how='left', on='full_id', suffixes=('_x', '_y'))
```

There is the extra thing you do not talk about. Do you have info on cols Attr1 and Attr2 on background_df that you would wish to keep instead of what might be in data_df?
If so, then this would need further checking on both _x and _y attr cols.

I like to use iterrows, but you specifically said no to that.